# What is the difference between two-level indexing with $ and [] compared to [][]?

Tags: r

If I have a list of vectors (e.g. `test_vector <- vector("character", 50)`), and I want to change the values by indices, what is the difference between the two commands?

`list_of_vectors$vector_name[index] <- assignment_value`

vs.

`list_of_vectors[vector_name_string][index] <- assignment_value`

In a loop, iterating over the index, the latter was extremely slow, became slower as it progressed, and yielded warnings: *Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.*

Why aren't both assignments the same?

Comment: Solved it myself. I should have used [[]][] instead of []. That was the problem.

Comment: for the second example, you probably want `listvectors[[vectorName]][index]`. A single [ pulls of a list with a single element.